# No matching provisioning profiles found error when uploading to app store

Tags: ios

I was trying to upload new version of my app but I encounter an error like:
[image]

I am using automatically manage signing:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: try changing Provisioning profile to manual

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, it was due to the product bundle identifier under the build setting was different from the one in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

We need to check product bundle identifier in below things

1.in Plist set your app bundle identifier

```
Bundle identifier      String       com.domainName.projectName
```

2.Product Bundle Identifier in Project and Target

```
 You need to set app bundle identifier in Build Settings of Project
 Then you need to set app bundle identifier in Build Settings of Target
```